# Automapper mapping exception with lists to lists

Tags: c#, automapper

I've got problem with Automapper. My mapping call looks like:

```
var dataContracts = MapperManager.Mapper.Map<List<Employee>, List<EmployeeDTO>>(entities.ToList());
```

Entity is `IQueryable<Employee>`

In my Mapper helper class I Have:

```
public class MapperManager
{
    public static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration { get; set; }

    private static IMapper _mapper { get; set; }

    public static IMapper Mapper
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mapper == null) {
                _mapper = MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();                    
            }

            return _mapper;
        }
    }

    public static void RegisterMappinngs()
    {

        MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            ...
            cfg.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDTO>().MaxDepth(5);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

RegisterMappings is called once on AppStartup in Global.asax
and after that I've Exception in Map operation:

```
var dataContracts = MapperManager.Mapper.Map<List<Employee>, List<EmployeeDTO>>(entities.ToList());
```

> Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types:
>   List`1 -> List`1 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[NAMESPACE.Employee, ASSEMBLY,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] ->
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[NAMESPACE2.EmployeeDTO, ASSEMBLY2,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Anyone can provide any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Best regards

Comment: Are you successfully able to map a single Employee -> EmployeeDTO?  Your configuration may not be complete.  What happens if you call `MapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` ?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, that was the answer:

MapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid()

When I called that, I got AMConfigurationException with unmaped property, deep inside another Employee property.

Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was because it was attempting to map Ids that should have been ignored

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error, I was able to run it in production, but the unit test failed , failed and failed.

**Make sure that you include your profile if you setup your own mapper configuration. Also double check your mappings.**

```
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            mc.AddProfile(new MyMissingProfile());
        });
        
        _mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
```